# Codeigniter 2 and codeception

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i have a clean CodeIgniter framework version 2 installed.
And created a phpunit test in /tests/unit/PostTest.php with following contents:

```
    <?php

    class PostTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
    private $CI;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database('testing');
    }

    public function testGetsAllPosts()
    {
        $this->CI->load->model('post');
        $posts = $this->CI->post->getAll();
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($posts));
    }
}
```

and this is my bootstrap: http://conversal.w0p.be/tests/unit/_bootstrap.phps

when i run codecept run unit --bedug i get this:
Running PostTest::testGetsAllPosts PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in /var/www/sites/conversal.w0p.be/tests/unit/PostTest.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP 1. {main}() /usr/bin/codecept:0
PHP 2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/bin/codecept:39
PHP 3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/share/php/Codeception/vendor/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:105
PHP 4. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/share/php/Codeception/vendor/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:188
PHP 5. Codeception\Command\Run->execute() /usr/share/php/Codeception/vendor/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:227
PHP 6. Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() /usr/share/php/Codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:57
PHP 7. Codeception\SuiteManager->run() /usr/share/php/Codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:89
PHP 8. Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun() /usr/share/php/Codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:130
PHP 9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /usr/share/php/Codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Runner.php:97
PHP 10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP 11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP 12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:772
PHP 13. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:751
PHP 14. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:650
PHP 15. PostTest->setUp() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:801
FATAL ERROR OCCURRED. TESTS NOT FINISHED.

it looks like it doens't load the _bootstrap?

Comment: Do you still have this bootrstrap file?  I see the link no longer works, but I'm trying to figure out how to to give Codeception access my Codeigniter code

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$this->CI = &get_instance();
```

It should be:

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
```